# numpy argsort vs sklearn NearestNeighbors

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I am building a recommendation system with a method for finding most similar items to a given item.

For that I could use the embedding of the items in features space and then apply a nearest neighbors search using [scikit-learn NearestNeighbors class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors). However, I could also compute the distance between all pairs of points and store it in a `np.ndarray` of shape `n_items, n_items` and use [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to find the top k indices (so the indices of the most similar items).

Which of those alternatives should be faster at finding the most similar items?

**EDIT:** I am talking about large sets of items

Thanks!

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. Is the array size very large or not? Why have you not coded both alternatives and found which is faster on your system?

Comment: The array size is large. I have not done profiling because I am looking for a conceptual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, sorting an array is going to be more computationally efficient than fitting a learned model like a nearest neighbors classifier. However, you may be to gain a runtime advantage if you only need to fit the model one time at the beginning.

Sorting an array with Numpy has a best time complexity of O(nlogn). If you have to sort every time you do a lookup, this might be inefficient. The [KDTree algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) that you can configure scikit-learn's NearestNeighbors class to use can be constructed in a time that is O(nlogn) and then lookups can be performed in a time that is O(logn). So if you only need to build the KDTree once at the beginning, it may be more efficient. Note that the search will have to compute distances from your feature vectors, so if your feature space is high-dimensional, this may end up being less efficient. And if you won't ever be encountering unseen data points it may be entirely wasteful.

Your decision here should probably be focused on usage rather than efficiency. A nearest neighbors classifier is typically useful if you have to classify brand new, never-before-seen data points. If you already have all the distances stored in a table for every data point your system will encounter, a learned classifier may not help you, because you can simply look up that point in your table or build a search tree to access the points from the distances you already have. If, however, your system will encounter data that you don't have in your table, you can train a classifier using the table as training data, and, e.g. allow the model to estimate distances that you don't have.

Note that a nearest neighbors classifier isn't the only type of model that is useful for classifying unseen data points, and all classifiers have pros and cons to consider. But first it is more important to decide if a learned model even makes sense for your application.

And as always when dealing with questions of speed it's important to implement and profile your options.

Comment: The [NearestNeighbor class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors) is just about finding similar points, not about classification.

Comment: The use case for [nearest neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) is to determine something about a new, unseen datapoint based on the examples that are closest to it in the training set. If you don't need to classify, and you don't have unseen data to consider, then you don't need the nearest neighbors model.

Comment: I am not talking about the k-nearest neighbors algorithm. I am talking about the NearestNeighbor class, for which documentation says "Unsupervised learner for implementing neighbor searches". Therefore I can use it to find closest data points.

Comment: Are you working with unseen data points? The nearest neighbors class (which uses a k-nearest neighbors algorithm) performs the search in parameter space. It computes a distance metric using your feature vectors. You already have a table of distances, so you don't need to recompute these. The KDTree algorithm, once fit, can perform searches quite fast, but if your feature space is high dimensional it will fit and probably search slowly. If you really want to use the model for a simple table lookup, it would be a good idea to profile both implementations and find out.

Comment: It makes more sense now, thank you. I should modify my question a bit

Comment: I edited the answer to discuss computational complexity a little bit. It's still important to profile if you're looking for speed.